# Shut down iPhone in simulator

Tags: iphone, settings, ios-simulator, save, shutdown

This might seem like a strange question, but can I actually shut down the iPhone and restart it in the iPhone simulator? I want to do this to see if my settings are saved and reloaded when the app is relaunched AFTER shutdown.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes. Press `Command`+`Q` to quit the simulator.

This will close all the apps running in the simulator.

Pressing the `home button` only returns to the home screen without quitting the apps(ios 4 or later) because of multitasking.

You can also double tap the home button, click and hold on the icons at the bottom of the screen till a red circle appear, and click on the red circle to close the running app.

Comment: it's ridiculous when go to main menu > Hardware and then you find only *reboot* but *not shutdown*

Answer (score 12):

As of XCode 9, the best way to close a single simulator is using the Cmd + W shortcut, or going to File -> Close Window.

Answer (score 3):

If your'e xcode 9.You can now shutdown the simulator by long-pressing the power button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I prefer this option as you can shut down only one if you have multiple simulators. `⌘+Q` kills all the simulators

Comment: Try doing this on iPhone X simulator :) Shutdown isn't present in settings->general too.

Comment: Can you seriously not close an iPhone X simulator by itself without Cmd+Q? Is this a joke?

Answer (score 3):

To close/shutdown one simulated device without closing other simulations, select the device you want to shut down then go to "File" and choose "Close Window".